# Perform action as soon as something is copied to the SD Card on Android

Tags: android

I am currently looking into developing an android app which will automatically copy files from select directories on the SD card to DropBox.

I am assuming that this would be done using a service, but how do I get the app to perform a particular action when something is saved to the SD card.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`FileObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) for this, but it will require an everlasting service, and users tend to dislike these -- hence, the existence and popularity of task killers.

A better approach would be to use a polling mechanism, via `AlarmManager`, where you check for changes every so often, and where the user can determine how frequently "every so often" is.

In either case, you have to deal with the fact that external storage is not always available (e.g., may be tied up by the desktop OS a device is tethered to). This will be somewhat easier with the polling model, as you can just skip a poll if you determine that external storage is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

this will require a device level permissions which is hard to get i guess,
in some extent some device may have to be rooted to do that as probably os
may think this as a virus.

but for starting i guess you need to create a service which is watching file operations and identifying operation which has target file system other then default file system.